# form_tag for create/update action rails 3

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3

My route file looks like this:

```
scope :locslug/:userslug do  
....
....

post 'rate/:stars' => 'articles#rate' :as => :rate_article
end
```

I'm trying to generate a form with an action that targets the **rate** action in articles. Ideally, when the form is submitted, a rating will either be created or updated. Elsewhere, I have that an article has_many ratings.

This doesn't work:

```
= form_tag rate_article_path, :method=>'post', :id => "rate_article" do
  =hidden_field_tag :article_id, @article.id
  =hidden_field_tag :stars, 0
  =hiden_field_tag :user, current_user.id
```

Help is very much appreciated. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

does rails shows some error? I think you have your route wrong: 'rate/:stars' tells rails to expect a parameter when you call rate_article_path (something link rate_article_path(5) for 5 stars)

you should have your route:

```
post 'rate/:article_id' => 'articles#rate' :as => :rate_article
```

your form:

```
= form_tag rate_article_path(@article), :method=>'post', :id => "rate_article" do
  =hidden_field_tag :stars, 0
```

now on your controller

```
def rate
  article = Article.find(params[:article_id])
  article.rates.create(:user => current_user, :stars => params[:stars])
end
```

(it's really simplified, you should do some validations, it's just to get the idea of what to do)

Comment: I did change my route to remove the **:stars** variable. But my problem was occuring because I was trying to use do a ajax post from my app.js file. For some reason, when I did that, the action which I post to was always wrong. I replaced it with *:remote => true* in the view, and everything works as I expected. Thanks for your help nonetheless.