# Rails form_tag nested with nested resources

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

I have routes that looks like this:

```
resources :teams do

  resources :plans do
    resources :charges
  end

  ...
```

I want to create a form using `form_tag` that points to my `charges_controller` create action. But I need some help...

The form I have currently looks like this (it's only a button, the submit is done in javascript):

```
= form_tag team_plan_charges_path([@team, plan]) do
  = content_tag "button", id: "customButton", class: "btn btn-primary" do
    Select plan
```

This results in the following error:

```
No route matches {:action=>"index", :controller=>"charges" ... missing required keys: [:plan_id]
```

I'm not sure how to set up the `form_tag` correctly based on my form, any ideas?

Comment: looks ok, try `form_tag team_plan_charges_path(@team, plan), method: :post`

Comment: try `rake routes` and paste the result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It should be something like this:

```
= form_tag @charge, team_plan_charge_path([@team, @plan]), method: :post do
  = content_tag "button", id: "customButton", class: "btn btn-primary" do
    Select plan
```

Answer (score 0):

I think,  `team_plan_charges_path([@team, plan])` should be something like  `team_plan_charges_path([@team, @plan, @charges])` 
where @plan and @charges should be in your charges controller, like

```
@plan = @team.plans.new
@charges = @plan.charges.new
```

assuming you have a has_many association between **Team** and **Plan** and **Plan** and **Charge**.
I am also assuming that plan is not some method in your *helpers* and as per the comments you have a `method: :post` 
That's the general idea, because your routes look like /team/:team:id/plan/:plan_id/charges probably.

Here is an [example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11304766/form-tag-for-create-update-action-rails-3) to look at.